# space between email icon amd email text in css .how do i move email id text to right side?

Tags: css, text, icons, move, space

[i need to move my email id text to right eqaul to icon of mailid like i have done to github and linkedin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCMjT.png) how to move  text of email that i have given in contact info to right side with some gap between mail icon and mail id text like remaining github , linked in text alignment .

```
.contactInfo {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(251, 249, 249, 0.943);
}

.title {
  color: rgb(78, 154, 116);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.contactInfo ul {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.contactInfo ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.contactInfo ul li .icon {
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(84, 152, 125);
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.contactInfo ul li span {
  color: #dbd8d8;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.contactInfo ul li p {
  padding:0px  50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.contactInfo ul li text {
  padding-left: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.contactInfo ul li a {
  color: rgb(243, 239, 239);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

i need to move my email id text to right eqaul to icon of mailid like i have done to github and linkedin

Comment: CSS, without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: That being said, it looks like this is probably breaking into a new line, simply because there isn't enough space available for both icon and text to go next to each other. So you'll have to _make_ more space, or reduce the space requirements of the content (like, smaller font-size, or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

For this I Guess Absolute wont work as it's worst practice of code. You can rather use flexbox.

Regarding Your example you can try this.
I am assuming you have icon class for left image and text class for right text

```
.contactInfo ul li
{
    display:flex;
    column-gap:20px;
}
.contactInfo ul li icon
{
      width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(84, 152, 125);
}
.contactInfo ul li text
{
    position:relative;
}
```

Hope It Works :)